# React Native axios call rises error when sending post to Django Rest Framework endpoint

Tags: react-native, django-rest-framework, axios

I have the following React Native method:

```
 const handleSignupPress = async () => {
    try {
      newUser = {
        username: email, 
        email: email, 
        first_name: '', 
        last_name: '', 
        is_staff: false,
        is_active: true, 
        is_superuser: false
      };
      await axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/access/users/', newUser);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
```

This method is sending a post to a Django Rest Framework endpoint that is available and working perfectly, but the axios call raises this error: `[Error: Network Error]`.

I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: could you check the network tab ? and add more details

Comment: The network tab gets nothing at all. All I get is in console tab: `Error: Network Error
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at EventTarget.handleError (xhr.js:91)
    at EventTarget.dispatchEvent (event-target-shim.js:818)
    at EventTarget.setReadyState (XMLHttpRequest.js:600)
    at EventTarget.__didCompleteResponse (XMLHttpRequest.js:395)
    at XMLHttpRequest.js:508
    at RCTDeviceEventEmitter.emit (EventEmitter.js:189)
    at MessageQueue.__callFunction (MessageQueue.js:416)
    at MessageQueue.js:109
    at MessageQueue.__guard (MessageQueue.js:364)``

Comment: with that axios instance you can consume another api of the web ? or the problem its just   your localhost?